# remove pictures from folder

Tags: find, rm, photo

I want to remove all the photos from a folder and keep the remaining files. 
I searched in the web and I found a tons of solutions like:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -delete
```

All the photos are jpeg, yes, but the main problem is that the photo's names don't end with their extension ".jpg".

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to delete *all* of the files within a folder? or all JPEG files within the folder? or a some subset of the JPEG files? It would be helpful to give examples of what you want to remove and what (if anything) you want to keep.

Comment: You could probably use file command and check that returned value is `JPEG image data`.

Comment: @steeldriver " photo

I want to remove all the photos from a folder and keep the remaining files" ( op, first line )

Comment: @Serg I modified the op thanks to the suggestion made by steeldriver, but I forgotten to notified it.

Comment: @Armen : Could you explain me how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do

```
for i in *; do 
    TESTRESULT=$(file --mime-type -b "$i"); 
    if [ "$TESTRESULT" == "image/jpeg" ]; then 
        echo "$i"; 
    fi;
done
```

If that prints the desired files, replace `echo "$i"` with `rm "$i"`

Comment: could you explain me how your code work?

Comment: for each file in directory check if its mimetype is jpeg if so echo its name (or if you replace echo with rm remove)

Answer (score 2):

Okay I have found a solution:

Try this command

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -delete
```

I tried this on Xubuntu 14.04 and it worked fine.
I hope this helps!

I know this is similar to your example but the example you gave didn't work for me. But this is a simpler one liner.

Comment: Did you read the question? The OP mentions this solution and explains that their files don't have the right extensions.

Comment: Yes, Don't worry. I double checked the question after submitting my answer and realized that. But I thought I would leave it on here in-case someone stumbled upon this page thinking it was another question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script to remove all images:

```
userX@ubuntu:~$ cat removeImages.sh 
#!/bin/bash
path=/home/userX/Downloads/*;
for file in $path
do
  fileInfo=`file "$file" |awk -F: '{print $2}'`
  if [[ $fileInfo =~ .*image.* ]]; then echo "Removing: " $file; rm $file; fi
done
```

You use second part of file `file "$file"` output and look for `image` keyword in it, and then remove the current file in the loop.

If you also want to remove bitmaps:

```
userX@ubuntu:~$ cat removeImages.sh 
#!/bin/bash
path=/home/userX/Downloads/*;
for file in $path
do
  fileInfo=`file "$file" |awk -F: '{print $2}'`
  if [[ $fileInfo =~ .*image.*]] || [[$fileInfo =~ .*bitmap.* ]]; 
  then echo "Removing: " $file; rm $file; fi
done
```